# Given a matrix $A$, for what value of $x$, will $Ax = x$ assuming length of $x = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

When thinking of $x$, I decided to try and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$ to see if I get a possible $x$.

$$\begin{align*}
\text{Eigenvalue} &= 1\\[5pt]
\text{Eigenvector} &= \begin{bmatrix}
1\\
-1\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\\[5pt]
\text{Eigenvalue} &= 0\\[5pt]
\text{Eigenvector} &= \begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

Both of the vectors do not have length as $1$, so I was wondering if I went wrong somewhere. Could someone shed some light?

Comment: There are a couple issues. You're missing an eigenvector, and why are you not free to normalize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *normalise* vectors. Indeed, if $x=[x_1,x_2,x_3]^T$, then $||x||=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$ and $$||\frac{x}{||x||}||=1$$

In the case of $x=[1,-1,1]^T$, we see $||x||=\sqrt 3$ so the vector $x_N=[\frac{1}{\sqrt3},\frac{-1}{\sqrt3},\frac{1}{\sqrt3}]^T$ is normalised (aka has length $1$).

Comment: The normalization part had completely skipped my head. We have covered so much in the past week, that I'm still unsure of a lot of things so thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The question is equivalent (if I understand it correctly that is..), that for a given $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 1\\ 
-1 & -1 & -1\\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}$$

and $$x=\begin{bmatrix} x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}$$
such that $|x|=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}=1$ (*)

we seek $x_1,x_2,x_3$ $$x_1+x_2+x_3=x_1\\x_1+x_2+x_3=-x_2$$

and the latter system reduces to $$x_2=-x_3\\x_1=-x_2$$
Now we can plug these to (*) and find $x_1, x_2, x_3$.